# Algorithm to assign one activity to each one individual in order to maximize the sum of the affinity scores

Tags: algorithm

Consider *N* individuals `(x1, x2 ... xn)` and *M* activities `(y1, y2 ... ym)`.

For each pair `(individual, activity)` there is a *score of affinity*, ***a*** that relates them.

The objective is to assign an activity to each individual to maximize the sum of the affinity scores of the chosen pairs. An activity can be assigned to only one individual and an individual can be associated with only one activity.

Below is an example of a matrix that reports the affinity of each pair.

```
    | x1  x2  x3
----+------------
y1  |  2   7   0
y2  |  7   7   9
y3  |  3   1   4
y4  |  5   4   4
```

I would like to know efficient algorithms that allow finding these pairs (individual, activity) that maximize the sum of affinities.

PS: I'm not an expert, so forgive me if that can have an obvious answer.

Comment: Hungarian algorithm?